# Selecting rows with specific text to count and sum

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I would need to determine the percentage of specific values by year.

The dataset has values as follows:

```
Year   Col                         Value 

2012  -20 p,                        12
2012  -20 points, d             20
2012  -20 points, by           24
2012  -20 p, new                32
2012  -30 p,                      1256
2012  -30 points, d             32
2012  -30 points, by           42
2012  -30 p, new               164
```

There are other years but for the example I selected only 2012. 
For each year, I would like to determine the percentage as:

- Count of values having `points` word in the text

Divided by values starting with `- 20`

Same for case with 30. 
Expected output for -20 in 2012:

```
(20+24)/(12+20+24+32)
```

I have tried as follows

```
        Select year,
        Col,
        Count(0) as Value
        , 100*count(0)/sum(count(case when Col like ‘-20%points%’ then 1 end) over (partition by year, substr(Col, 1,2))) as pct_20
        /* Same for 40 poin

    ts */
    From table1

Where /* conditions */
Group by 1,2
```

But I got the error Ordered analytical functions can not be nested.

Comment: I can't figure out what values are in what column.

Comment: I edited the format. Unfortunately by phone is not easy to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select year, substr(col, 1, 2),
       sum(case when col like '%points%' then value end) / sum(value)
from t
group by 1, 2;
```

Based on your comment:

```
select year, substr(col, 1, 2),
       sum(case when col like '%points%' then 1.0 end) / count(*)
from t
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Value comes from count (0). May I use it within sum? I got this error: `cannot best aggregate operations` by doing `sum (case when col like’%points%’ then count(0) end) /nullif(sum(count(0))))`

Comment: I think this can be fixed using a sub query

Answer (score 0):

You can only nest an aggregate within an OLAP function, but not vice versa:

```
    , 100*count(*)/NULLIF(sum(count(case when Col like ‘-20%points%’ then 1 end))
                          over (partition by year, substr(Col, 1,2)), 0) as pct_20
```

Comment: Is it because of  the bracket?

Comment: In case of division of zero (very small number) could you please tell me how to add a condition in the code? Unfortunately I cannot see if it works  because of this error :(

Comment: Yep, bracket in the wrong place. Regarding the error `, NULLIF fixes that. In fact it should be used whenever you divide, I just forgot it

Comment: Thank you dnoeth. Now I can see that the problem is in counting the total. I am doing something wrong in the substr function.  it should count  the total of 20 and 30 separately, in order to determine the percentage of 20 and the percentage of 30 over their own total count

Comment: I think the problem is in the partition. The values unfortunately do not take into account the total. If I have 2012 as first year, then 2013, the values for 2012 are exactly the same (not in percentage within that year). In 2013, they have been calculate probably taken into account values from 2012. I think my code is missing something in this direction. Maybe in the first count before division I should consider value having 20 points in the name?